# Create a lag up to a specific value in a column R

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, mutate

I have a timeseries dataset in R with 17 time points. For each group of individuals (named ID), individuals were infected at the beginning of the time series (at timepoint 0). In some groups, individuals were re-infected one or more times throughout the time series.

I have a variable for days since first timepoint/ first infection, and another variable with days since previous check-up, and another variable denotes the timepoint of any infection after the first.

I would like to create a new variable with days since any infection. If there is no infection after the first, this should be the same as the column for days since first timepoint/infection. If there are infections after the first, this should be the summation of days since previous check-up, until the timepoint of the additional infection.

I think what I should be doing is taking infections occurring after timepoint 1, and adding together the days since previous check-up, until I experience another timepoint with infection.

I have tried multiple iterations of cumulative sums lagged for the rows of days since previous check up above until day 0 is reached, but I cannot figure out how to do this for groups with more than one infection.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

ID: Individual ID for full timeseries
timepoint: time point in time series
status: Recruitment= time of first infection and beginning of time series. Follow up = all timepoints
days_total_length: Number of days since first infection/ beginning of time series
days_from_previous_round: number of days since last timepoint/ follow-up
infection: point of (any) infection

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble::tribble(
           ~ID, ~timepoint,       ~status, ~days_total_length, ~days_from_previous_round, ~infection,
    "Sero-035",          0, "Recruitment",                 0L,                        0L,          1,
    "Sero-035",       0.25,   "Follow-up",                 7L,                        7L,         NA,
    "Sero-035",          1,   "Follow-up",                31L,                       24L,         NA,
    "Sero-035",          2,   "Follow-up",                59L,                       28L,         NA,
    "Sero-035",          3,   "Follow-up",                90L,                       31L,         NA,
    "Sero-035",          4,   "Follow-up",               120L,                       30L,         NA,
    "Sero-035",          5,   "Follow-up",               151L,                       31L,         NA,
    "Sero-035",          6,   "Follow-up",               181L,                       30L,         NA,
    "Sero-035",          7,   "Follow-up",               211L,                       30L,         NA,
    "Sero-035",          8,   "Follow-up",               242L,                       31L,         NA,
    "Sero-035",          9,   "Follow-up",               272L,                       30L,         NA,
    "Sero-035",         10,   "Follow-up",               294L,                       22L,         NA,
    "Sero-035",         11,   "Follow-up",               334L,                       40L,         NA,
    "Sero-035",         12,   "Follow-up",               364L,                       30L,         NA,
    "Sero-036",          0, "Recruitment",                 0L,                        0L,          1,
    "Sero-036",       0.25,   "Follow-up",                 7L,                        7L,         NA,
    "Sero-036",          1,   "Follow-up",                31L,                       24L,         NA,
    "Sero-036",          2,   "Follow-up",                59L,                       28L,         NA,
    "Sero-036",          3,   "Follow-up",                91L,                       32L,          1,
    "Sero-036",          4,   "Follow-up",               121L,                       30L,         NA,
    "Sero-036",          5,   "Follow-up",               154L,                       33L,         NA,
    "Sero-036",          6,   "Follow-up",               184L,                       30L,         NA,
    "Sero-036",          7,   "Follow-up",               214L,                       30L,         NA,
    "Sero-036",          8,   "Follow-up",               247L,                       33L,         NA,
    "Sero-036",          9,   "Follow-up",               278L,                       31L,         NA,
    "Sero-036",         10,   "Follow-up",               311L,                       33L,         NA,
    "Sero-036",         11,   "Follow-up",               341L,                       30L,         NA,
    "Sero-036",         12,   "Follow-up",               372L,                       31L,          1,
    "Sero-040",          0, "Recruitment",                 0L,                        0L,          1,
    "Sero-040",       0.25,   "Follow-up",                 7L,                        7L,         NA,
    "Sero-040",          1,   "Follow-up",                31L,                       24L,         NA,
    "Sero-040",          2,  "Recurrence",                53L,                       22L,          1,
    "Sero-040",          3,   "Follow-up",                84L,                       31L,         NA,
    "Sero-040",          4,   "Follow-up",               115L,                       31L,         NA,
    "Sero-040",          5,   "Follow-up",               149L,                       34L,         NA,
    "Sero-040",          6,  "Recurrence",               171L,                       22L,          1,
    "Sero-040",          7,   "Follow-up",               196L,                       25L,         NA,
    "Sero-040",          8,   "Follow-up",               224L,                       28L,         NA,
    "Sero-040",          9,   "Follow-up",               260L,                       36L,          1,
    "Sero-040",         10,  "Recurrence",               267L,                        7L,          1,
    "Sero-040",         11,   "Follow-up",               291L,                       24L,         NA,
    "Sero-040",         12,   "Follow-up",               332L,                       41L,          1,
    "Sero-040",         13,   "Follow-up",               366L,                       34L,         NA,
    "Sero-041",          0, "Recruitment",                 0L,                        0L,          1,
    "Sero-041",       0.25,   "Follow-up",                 6L,                        6L,         NA,
    "Sero-041",          1,   "Follow-up",                31L,                       25L,         NA,
    "Sero-041",          2,  "Recurrence",                52L,                       21L,          1,
    "Sero-041",          3,   "Follow-up",                84L,                       32L,         NA,
    "Sero-041",          4,  "Recurrence",               104L,                       20L,          1,
    "Sero-041",          5,   "Follow-up",               135L,                       31L,         NA,
    "Sero-041",          6,   "Follow-up",               168L,                       33L,         NA,
    "Sero-041",          7,   "Follow-up",               204L,                       36L,         NA,
    "Sero-041",          8,   "Follow-up",               237L,                       33L,         NA,
    "Sero-041",          9,  "Recurrence",               252L,                       15L,          1,
    "Sero-041",         10,  "Recurrence",               274L,                       22L,          1,
    "Sero-041",         11,   "Follow-up",               305L,                       31L,         NA,
    "Sero-041",         12,  "Recurrence",               329L,                       24L,          1,
    "Sero-041",         13,   "Follow-up",               361L,                       32L,         NA,
    "Sero-042",          0, "Recruitment",                 0L,                        0L,          1,
    "Sero-042",       0.25,   "Follow-up",                 7L,                        7L,         NA,
    "Sero-042",          1,   "Follow-up",                32L,                       25L,          1,
    "Sero-042",          2,   "Follow-up",                59L,                       27L,         NA,
    "Sero-042",          3,   "Follow-up",               101L,                       42L,         NA,
    "Sero-042",          4,   "Follow-up",               134L,                       33L,         NA,
    "Sero-042",          5,   "Follow-up",               168L,                       34L,         NA,
    "Sero-042",          6,   "Follow-up",               199L,                       31L,          1,
    "Sero-042",          7,   "Follow-up",               234L,                       35L,         NA,
    "Sero-042",          8,   "Follow-up",               265L,                       31L,          1,
    "Sero-042",          9,   "Follow-up",               289L,                       24L,         NA,
    "Sero-042",         10,   "Follow-up",               331L,                       42L,         NA,
    "Sero-042",         11,   "Follow-up",               364L,                       33L,         NA,
    "Sero-042",         12,   "Follow-up",               395L,                       31L,         NA,
    "Sero-043",          0, "Recruitment",                 0L,                        0L,          1,
    "Sero-043",       0.25,   "Follow-up",                 7L,                        7L,         NA,
    "Sero-043",          1,   "Follow-up",                31L,                       24L,         NA,
    "Sero-043",          2,   "Follow-up",                59L,                       28L,         NA,
    "Sero-043",          3,   "Follow-up",                90L,                       31L,         NA,
    "Sero-043",          4,   "Follow-up",               120L,                       30L,         NA,
    "Sero-043",          5,   "Follow-up",               151L,                       31L,         NA,
    "Sero-043",          6,   "Follow-up",               181L,                       30L,         NA,
    "Sero-043",          7,   "Follow-up",               211L,                       30L,         NA,
    "Sero-043",          8,   "Follow-up",               242L,                       31L,         NA,
    "Sero-043",          9,   "Follow-up",               272L,                       30L,         NA,
    "Sero-043",         10,   "Follow-up",               302L,                       30L,         NA,
    "Sero-043",         11,   "Follow-up",               332L,                       30L,         NA,
    "Sero-043",         12,   "Follow-up",               364L,                       32L,         NA,
    "Sero-047",          0, "Recruitment",                 0L,                        0L,          1,
    "Sero-047",       0.25,   "Follow-up",                 7L,                        7L,         NA,
    "Sero-047",          1,   "Follow-up",                33L,                       26L,          1,
    "Sero-047",          2,   "Follow-up",                62L,                       29L,         NA,
    "Sero-047",          3,   "Follow-up",                98L,                       36L,          1,
    "Sero-047",          4,   "Follow-up",               129L,                       31L,          1,
    "Sero-047",          5,   "Follow-up",               161L,                       32L,          1,
    "Sero-047",          6,   "Follow-up",               192L,                       31L,         NA,
    "Sero-047",          7,   "Follow-up",               232L,                       40L,         NA,
    "Sero-047",          8,   "Follow-up",               264L,                       32L,         NA,
    "Sero-047",          9,   "Follow-up",               297L,                       33L,         NA,
    "Sero-047",         10,   "Follow-up",               327L,                       30L,         NA,
    "Sero-047",         11,   "Follow-up",               360L,                       33L,         NA,
    "Sero-047",         12,   "Follow-up",               388L,                       28L,         NA
    )
```